# Unable to observe page navigation using F# Async support in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#

I'm unable to observe page navigation.

Command:

```
member x.AddBankcard =    DelegateCommand( (fun _ -> async { do! navigate() 
                                                           } |> Async.RunSynchronously 
                                                             |> ignore ) ,
                                            fun _ -> true) :> ICommand
```

Publish navigation request:

```
let navigate() =

    account 
     |> PageRequest.AddBankcard 
     |> broadcastToAsync pageRequesthandlers
```

Notify subscribers of request:

```
let broadcastToAsync<'a> (handlers:(list<'a -> Async<unit>>)) (msg:'a) : Async<unit> =

    async { handlers |> List.map (fun handle -> async { do! handle msg }) |> ignore }
```

Handle navigation:

```
let handle = function
    | PageRequest.AddBankcard _ ->
        page |> function 
        | :? UI.AddBankcard as pageRequest ->
            ...
            async { do! navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> Async.AwaitTask }

        | _ -> async { () }
    | _ -> async { () }
```

**Note:**

1. No page navigation occurs.
2. I don't receive any exceptions.
3. I don't see any clues in the output window
4. My hunch is I'm not using async correctly.

   async { do! navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> Async.AwaitTask }

**UPDATED:**

I also tried the following:

```
let navigationPage = (app:?>Application).MainPage:?>NavigationPage

let navigate () = async  {
    do! navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> awaitTask
}

navigate() |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore
```

[Here's the source code](https://github.com/bizmonger/GetRide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async {...}` block is only needed when code must execute after the async/task operation has completed.

For navigation, there generally isn't anything to do afterwards (the exception is some MVVM frameworks).`ignore` is required as the function signature requires that unit is returned and the navigation methods return a `Task`. In C# a `Task` is started when called, while `async` blocks in F# are not.

The following code is a very simple example of navigation without the need for the `async` keyword or `Async.AwaitTask` etc.

```
open Xamarin.Forms
open Xamarin.Forms.Xaml

type NextPage(app:Application) = 
    inherit ContentPage() 

    let button = Button(Text = "Back")
    do 
        button.Clicked.Add (fun _ -> app.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync () |> ignore )
        base.Content <- nextButton

type MainPage(app:Application) =
    inherit ContentPage()

    let nextButton = Button(Text = "Next")
    do 
        nextButton.Clicked.Add (fun _ -> 
            let nextPage = NextPage app
            app.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync nextPage |> ignore )

        base.Content <- nextButton

type App() as this =
    inherit Application()
    do this.MainPage <- NavigationPage(MainPage(this))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that the function `broadcastToAsync` doesn't really perform any actions:

```
let broadcastToAsync<'a> (handlers:(list<'a -> Async<unit>>)) (msg:'a) : Async<unit> =
    async { handlers |> List.map (fun handle -> async { do! handle msg }) |> ignore }
```

The reason is it creates a list of `async`s and then it `ignore`s it.

I suggest you change `List.map` to `List.iter` remove the `|> ignore` and invoke `Async.RunSynchronously`:

```
let broadcastToAsync handlers msg =
    handlers |> List.iter (fun handle -> handle msg |> Async.RunSynchronously )

"msg" |> broadcastToAsync [ 
        fun msg -> async { printfn "1: %A" msg}
        fun msg -> async { printfn "2: %A" msg} ] 

// 1: "msg"
// 2: "msg"
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still getting an exception on: 
async { navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> Async.AwaitTask |> Async.RunSynchronously |> ignore }

Comment: What message do you get?

Comment: My app just hangs now with: navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult |> Async.Ignore

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
let navigationPage = (app:?>Application).MainPage:?>NavigationPage
navigationPage.PushAsync(pageRequest) |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
```

Here's some code for popping the page off the stack:

```
app |> function
| :? Application as xForms -> 

let navigationPage = xForms.MainPage:?>NavigationPage
navigationPage.PopAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
```